# Text center and uneven flow?

Tags: html, css

Why is my text not centered & why is my is my floats not stacked evenly:
https://jsfiddle.net/t5mLm8p6/2/

```
    <H1 class="header-text"> SPECIAL COLORSHIFTING RED/CYAN INLAY FROM REDA </H1> 

    <div class="images-on-left-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_02_1.jpg" width="577" height="417" />
    </div>

    <div class="images-on-right-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_03.jpg" width="623" height="417" />
    </div>


    <H1 class="header-text"> FUNKY URBAN INLAY FROM ZEGNA  REDA</H1> 

    <div class="images-on-left-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_06_1.jpg" width="623" height="416" />
    </div>

    <div class="images-on-right-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_05.jpg" width="577" height="416" />
    </div>

    <H1 class="header-text"> CLASSIC BLUE PATTERN FROM VITALE BARBERIS</H1> 

    <div class="images-on-left-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_08.jpg" width="575" height="416" />
    </div>


    <div class="images-on-right-side" >
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_09.jpg" width="625" height="417" />
    </div>
```

I try to make the divs 6 divs/images stand side by side:
Like here: http://postimg.org/image/urstgg0s7/

But the next text a margin options makes it uneven for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your divs in a row. It should be like this--

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red
}
.row h1 {
  text-align: center
}
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px;
}
.row div > img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <H1 class="header-text"> SPECIAL COLORSHIFTING RED/CYAN INLAY FROM REDA </H1> 

  <div class="images-on-left-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_02_1.jpg" width="577" height="417" />
  </div>

  <div class="images-on-right-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_03.jpg" width="623" height="417" />
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <H1 class="header-text"> FUNKY URBAN INLAY FROM ZEGNA  REDA</H1> 

  <div class="images-on-left-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_06_1.jpg" width="623" height="416" />
  </div>

  <div class="images-on-right-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_05.jpg" width="577" height="416" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <H1 class="header-text"> CLASSIC BLUE PATTERN FROM VITALE BARBERIS</H1> 

  <div class="images-on-left-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_08.jpg" width="575" height="416" />
  </div>


  <div class="images-on-right-side">
    <img src="http://www.stock11.ch/media/wysiwyg/inlays/Landingpage_1200pix_inlay-page_09.jpg" width="625" height="417" />
  </div>
</div>
```

\

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you know how to make it not stretch on mobile devices and keep an even resizing? Looks a little stretched here when i run snippet.

Comment: Images are stretched because I have specified width in css. You can customize it as per your requirement.

Comment: The row css, didn't fix it. I still have these unevenly align images? Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What problem are you facing.? Can you add a screenshot.?